# Unable to execute MySql stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

**In MySql:**

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testdb`.`Check_UserId_Sproc` //
CREATE PROCEDURE `testdb`.`Check_UserId_Sproc` (IN User_Id NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
 select count(*) from demo_user where userid = User_Id;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**In C#:**

```
public DataTable ExecuteParameterizedSelectCommand(string CommandName, CommandType cmdType,MySqlParameter[] param)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

            using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

                    try
                    {
                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                        }

                        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            da.Fill(table);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    return table;
                }
            }
        }


    public DataTable checkExistingUserId()
            {
                MySqlDBHelper oHelper = new MySqlDBHelper();
                MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[]
                {
                    new MySqlParameter("User_Id", 'DemoId')
                };
                return oHelper.ExecuteParameterizedSelectCommand("Check_UserId_Sproc", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
            }
```

When I try to execute the **checkExistingUserId()**, I get following exception:

```
Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE testdb.Check_UserId_Sproc; expected 1, got 0
```

May be I am doing a silly mistake but I am not able to figure it out. I am new to mysql and trying to work around it.

When I debug the array contains the parameter as seen in below image, but it is not collected by the SP.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: DO you passing MySqlParameter[] param to the function?

Comment: ExecuteParameterizedSelectCommand

Comment: Yah! As you can see I am passing it..  oHelper.ExecuteParameterizedSelectCommand("Check_UserId_Sproc", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);

Comment: in your code:  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; should be cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

Comment: Solved the issue.. Really a silly mistake. ;) ... thanks a lot

Comment: I posted it as an answer vote in your free time :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

should be

```
cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
```